# Google Analytics cookie data into database from webform

Tags: java, google-analytics, tracking, crm

I am trying to capture data from the google analytics cookie and have it populate hidden fields which will then send that information to my database in Silverpop. I have the UA code inserted on my webform, and via google analytics I can see that there is someone on the site(me).  But I have tried several variations of javascript I have found on here to extract the campaign and source from the google cookie, and on form submit, have that information sent to my database. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide an example of the cookie value and what you want to get out of it. As in "Here is the cookie value.  Here is the value within that value I want"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, just gonna throw it out there that since GA uses first party cookies, you can use server-side code to parse the cookie.  I don't know java well enough to give you that code, but the info is stored in the `__utmz` cookie and the value looks something like this:

`21733335.1344455611.17.2.utmcsr=camp_source|utmccn=camp_name|utmcmd=camp_medium|utmctr=camp_term|utmcct=camp_content`

The leading numbers and dots are a hash and visitor id and other stuff you don't really need to worry about, so you can just strip it. Then you can just explode at the pipe and will have an array of `name=value` pairs that you can further split at the equal sign.

I just mention this because it would be more efficient and tamper-proof to do it server-side. You don't need to even worry about passing it in a form; you can do it on the very first page view request.

But if you really want to do this with client-side code, or need some guidance about parsing the cookie, here is the javascript example:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
// function to retrieve the GA campaign values
function getGACampaignCodes() {
  var cv = {};
  var utmz=document.cookie.match(/ __utmz=([^;]*)/);
  if (utmz!=null&&typeof(utmz[1])!='undefined') {
    utmz = utmz[1];
    utmz = utmz.replace(/^[0-9.]+/,'').split('|');
    for (var c=0,l=utmz.length;c<l;c++) {
      var cn = utmz[c].split('=');
      switch (cn[0]) {
        case 'utmcsr' : cv.source=cn[1];
        case 'utmccn' : cv.name=cn[1];
        case 'utmcmd' : cv.medium=cn[1];
        case 'utmctr' : cv.term=cn[1];
        case 'utmcct' : cv.content=cn[1];
      }
    }
  }
  return cv;
}

// function to populate the hidden fields
function addGAToFormFields() {
  var cv = getGACampaignCodes();
  var f = document.forms['someForm'];
  for (c in cv)
    if (cv.hasOwnProperty(c))
      f['ga['+c+']'].value = cv[c];
}

// call this when document is ready
addGAToFormFields();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Not sure what the java version would look like but this is an example of the posted vars in php:

```
Array
(
    [ga] => Array
        (
            [source] => camp_source
            [name] => camp_name
            [medium] => camp_medium
            [term] => camp_term
            [content] => camp_content
        )

)
```